# symfony2 Multidatabase login or change database by host

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

It is possible in symfony2 and fosuserbundle (or inner) to make it:

When I enter to site by host example.com I choose "example" database, then I can login to user in this database. When I enter to site by host exaple2.com I choose "exaple2" database where are other users and data.

Routing for both host I wanna have this same.

Edit:

I trying it now with MongoDB. I can create user for one datebase but can't login becouse it throw "Invalid credentials".

Config:

```
doctrine_mongodb:
    connections:
        pl:
            server: mongodb://localhost:27017
        en:
            server: mongodb://localhost:27017
    document_managers:
        pl:
            connection: pl
            mappings:
                AcmeBundle: ~
                FOSUserBundle: ~
        en:
            connection: en
            mappings:
                AcmeBundle: ~
                FOSUserBundle: ~
```

Request listener

```
class RequestListener
{
protected $dm;

public function setDmManager(ObjectManager $dm)
{
   $this->dm = $dm;
}
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
        $dbname = $event->getRequest()->getLocale();
        $this->dm->getConfiguration()->setDefaultDB($dbname);

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is quite doable using [Event Listeners](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html) like OnKernelRequest, I've got an application that does just that with MongoDB.

I name each DB according to domain & subdomain (ie: forums-mysite)

Then I use an Event Listener on OnKernelRequest to get the host name, break it down & load the appropriate database. Those lines should help:

```
    $request = $event->getRequest();
    $currentHost = $request->getHttpHost();
```

That is to get the host, then you need to parse it (with `explode()` or the such) to get the database name.

```
$this->dm->getConfiguration()->setDefaultDB($dbname);
```

That is to switch DB, but `$this->dm` is the `DocumentManager` for mongoDB  so it could be different for SQL and the `EntityManager`, you'll have to look up the appropriate method.

Hope this helps a bit.